# Placing the integers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ on a circle ( for $n>1$) in some special order

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

For which integer $n>1$ can we place the integers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ on a circle (say boundary of $S^1$ ) in some order such that for each $s \in \{1,2,\ldots,\dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}\}$ , there exist a connected subset of the circle on which the sum of the integers placed is exactly $s$?

Comment: @YogUrt I don't understand your example. We're supposed to put the integers 1 through n in some order--how does your example do that?

Comment: @Joey Zou , Sorry, my answer has been given  to another question: to find and place $n$ integers with connected sums from 1 to S. The comment with example is deleted.

Comment: I have examples for n≤23 .

Comment: I don't know why this is tagged "general-topology" and "connectedness".  The role of the "circle" here is completely superficial; this is just a question about labellings of finite cyclically ordered sets.

Comment: I looked for solutions with the additional property that no sum appears more than twice, again by generating random permutations of each size and testing them, and I found examples up to $n=11$.  Maybe some progress could be made by looking at this stronger conjecture.

Comment: For example, with $n=11$ there are $111$ connected subsets and $66$ possible sums.  I found $(6, 1, 11, 5, 3, 2, 7, 4, 9, 10, 8)$ for which there are either one or two connected subsets for each sum.

Comment: Do we know the complexity of such a problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, recursively inserting $n$ into a solution to the $n-1$ problem doesn't generate enough solutions to answer the question. This strategy only reaches two solutions for $n=16$: $(1, 6, 7, 16, 12, 13, 4, 11, 5, 15, 3, 14, 2, 10, 9, 8)$ and $(1, 7, 6, 11, 4, 5, 14, 3, 16, 9, 10, 8, 12, 2, 13, 15)$. It doesn't find a solution for $n=17$, although other solutions do exist.

Comment: For what it's worth: it's enough to ckeck  for $n < s \le \cdots \lfloor n(n+1)/4 \rfloor$

Comment: @leonbloy : Why is it enough to check for $n < s \le \cdots \lfloor n(n+1)/4 \rfloor$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev: Because if some consecutive set covers a sum $s$ then its complement (also consecutive) covers a sum $s'=n(n+1)/2 -s$. So you need to check only the (say) lower half. Further, the range $1\cdots n$ is trivially fulfilled.

Comment: @leonbloy : I have posted an answer , could you please check it ? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think I have got an answer : The arrangement is possible for any $n\ge 1$ .

Proof :

$\underline {case 1}$ , $n$ is even :

$n$ is even , so pair the numbers $1,2,...,n$ into $n/2$ pairs with the two numbers in each pair adding to $n+1$ i.e. the pairing is like $\{1,n\} ; \{2,n-1\} ; ...;\{\dfrac n2 , \dfrac n2+1\}$ . We claim that any circular arrangement of the numbers $1,2,...,n$ that keeps the numbers in each pair adjacent to one another gives all possible sum values from $1 $  to $\dfrac {n(n+1)}2$ . To see this , consider any $s$ as $1\le s \le \dfrac {n(n+1)}2$ , by division algorithm , there are integers $q,r$ such that $s=q(n+1)+r$ , where $0\le r\le n$ and $0 \le q \le n/2$ . If $r=0$ then we choose any $q$ consecutive pairs , as numbers in each pair are adjacent , this gives a connected subset with sum ( since each pair has sum $n+1$) $q(n+1)=q(n+1)+r(=0)=s$ ; if $r>0$ ( and so that $q < n/2)$ , we choose the connected subset to be beginning with $r$ and then $q$ consecutive pairs clockwise or anticlock wise as appropriate , obtaining a sum equal to $r+q(n+1)=s$

[Note :In $s=(n+1)q+r$ , the inequality $0\le r \le n$ comes from division algorithm but the bounds $0\le q \le n/2$ does not come directly from division algorithm ; it is due to as follows : $q(n+1)=s-r\le s \le \dfrac {n(n+1)}2$ so $q \le n/2$ , and $q(n+1)=s-r\ge1-r\ge1-n=-(n-1)>-(n+1)$ , so that $q>-1$ , then since $q$ is an integer , we get $q \ge 0$ ]

$\underline {case 2}$ , $n$ is odd :

$n$ is odd ,then we form $\dfrac {n+1}2$ pairs each with sum $n$ , thinking of the singleton $n$ as a degenerate pair ; i.e. $\{1,n-1\};\{2,n-2\};...;\{\dfrac {n-1}2 , \dfrac {n+1}2\};\{n\}$ are the required pairs . Here also , any  arrangement that keeps the numbers in each pair adjacent to one another gives all possible sum , the justification being same as that of the previous one .

Comment: Wow, very nice one, congratulations for a beatiful proof!

Comment: @jpvee : Thank you very much for taking the trouble to look  at the proof :)

Comment: Such a cute and simple solution! It also gives a nice lower bound $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor!$ for the number of solutions (not counting rotations and reflections).

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is not meant as an answer to the OP's question, but the space in the comment fields is too limited, so I put my comment here.

Using brute (computer) force, I managed to find solutions for all $n\leq 26$, and it is quite likely that solutions for larger $n$ can be found. I still can't make up my mind, though, whether or not I believe that there is an integer $N$ for which the problem has no solutions:

I modified my program to count the number of possible solutions out of all permutations of the integers $1,\ldots,n$ on the circle (not counting rotations and reflections) and looked at the ratios of these numbers:

```
2: 1 solution(s) found (out of 1 possible). Ratio is 1.0
3: 1 solution(s) found (out of 1 possible). Ratio is 1.0
4: 2 solution(s) found (out of 3 possible). Ratio is 0.6666666666666666
5: 10 solution(s) found (out of 12 possible). Ratio is 0.8333333333333334
6: 41 solution(s) found (out of 60 possible). Ratio is 0.6833333333333333
7: 126 solution(s) found (out of 360 possible). Ratio is 0.35
8: 537 solution(s) found (out of 2520 possible). Ratio is 0.2130952380952381
9: 3956 solution(s) found (out of 20160 possible). Ratio is 0.19623015873015873
10: 19776 solution(s) found (out of 181440 possible). Ratio is 0.10899470899470899
11: 76340 solution(s) found (out of 1814400 possible). Ratio is 0.04207451499118166
12: 388047 solution(s) found (out of 19958400 possible). Ratio is 0.019442791005291005
13: 2775155 solution(s) found (out of 239500800 possible). Ratio is 0.011587247307733419
14: 15013424 solution(s) found (out of 3113510400 possible). Ratio is 0.004822024683135794
```

The program is currently busy to get the figures for $n=15$. I'm sure it can be somewhat optimized, but I don't expect that many additional values can be computed in acceptable time, so there probably won't be much more insight than what's available already:

It is clear to see that while the absolute numbers of admissible permutations grow with $n$, the ratios with respect to the total numbers of permutations decrease, but they do so quite irregularly, note that the ratios for $n=8$ and $n=9$ are quite close whereas in other places there is a drop by more than 50%, so it is not only size that matters, but possibly some number theoretic constellations.

So, this limited evidence supports both possible propositions: The growing number of solutions suggests that there is a solution for every integer, and the decreasing ratios as well as the irregularity in the numbers of solutions could be a sign that eventually there might be a number $N$ for which no solution exists.

Can anyone provide some additional thoughts on the problem? I think that it is quite a gem, but I don't really have an idea how to tackle it.

Comment: Addendum: Meanwhile the sequence of distinct solutions has been submitted to the OEIS as [A272135](https://oeis.org/A272135). It also gives the numbers for $n=15$ and $n=16$ which yield the ratios $0.001243163963278050$ and $0.000416230553507339$.

Comment: I have posted an answer , could you please take a look ...?

Comment: Looks correct to me, very nice!