# Existence of a special type of injection $f:\mathbb N \to S^1$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb N$ relating to connectedness

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, number-theory, connectedness

Does there exist an injective function $f:\mathbb N \to S^1$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb N$ , there exist a connected subset (depending on $n$) $A \subseteq S^1$ with more than one point such that $\{n\}=f^{-1}(A)$ ?

If this is not true then I ask slightly weaker : Does there exist an injective function $f:\mathbb N \to S^1$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb N$ , there exist a connected subset (depending on $n$) $A \subseteq S^1$ with more than one point such that $\sum_{k\in f^{-1}(A)}k=n$ ?

Both these questions are motivated from this [Placing the integers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ on a circle ( for $n>1$) in some special order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603906/placing-the-integers-1-2-ldots-n-on-a-circle-for-n1-in-some-special)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can easily do this.  For instance, you can let $f(n)=e^{i/n}$ and take $A=\{e^{it}:1/(n+1)< t\leq 1/n\}$.

Comment: Ah! so , infact the first situation is indeed possible

Comment: I wonder , what would happen if the set of natural numbers is replaced by the set of rational numbers ; and then say if I also want the injection to be continuous ...

Comment: You can do it even with the rationals.  For instance, the set of endpoints in the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the rationals, and so you can take a Cantor set in the circle and let $A$ for each point be an interval that grows into the neighboring "hole" in the Cantor set.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further , or should I ask a different question ? The same could be ask for reals also ; and I think a characterization for such infinite sets for which such a function  is possible would be interesting ..

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question; it would take a decent amount of space to explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a function. Let $f(n)=\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}\right)$. Then take $A$ to be the intersection of $[\frac{1}{n+1}-\varepsilon,\frac{1}{n+1}+\varepsilon]\times\Bbb R_+$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough.